# Mensaje Error "en proceso..." Visual studio en proyecto Web Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Necesito ayuda con esto por favor, no se si le pasa a alguien mas.

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web asp.net c# en visual studio.

Anoche guarde el proyecto y hoy cuando quise abrirlo uno de los formularios web no me muestra el código de diseño .aspx. Me muestra la siguiente ventada:

[image: lleva horas así]

Pero solo es el archivo .aspx el .aspx.cs donde esta el código c# se muestra normal.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda :(

Post: la versión de Visual studio es 2019 community

Answer (score 0):

A mí me daba este error una vez. Lo resolví reinstalando el visual studio.

También tengo el 2019 community.